# Server Connection With Perl Not Using Socket

Tags: perl, networking

I need to connect to a server from another server using Perl.  I am not needing a socket connection, just testing the connection to make sure I can open it.  Looking for any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Updated question with needing open the connection.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a good start ?

```
perl -le '
    system("ping -c1 $ARGV[0] &>/dev/null");
    if ($? == 0) {
        print "Remote is pingable"
    }
    else{
        print "Remote non pingable"
    }
' google.com
```

or using ternary operator :

```
perl -le '
    print system("ping -c1 $ARGV[0] &>/dev/null") ?
         "Remote non pingable" : "Remote is pingable"
' google.com
```